# Install tensorflow error for Go under ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, go, tensorflow, installation

I installed tensorflow for Go with following steps, no error message shows.

```
TF_TYPE="cpu" # Change to "gpu" for GPU support
TARGET_DIRECTORY='/usr/local'
curl -L \
   "https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-${TF_TYPE}-$(go env GOOS)-x86_64-1.4.0.tar.gz" |
sudo tar -C $TARGET_DIRECTORY -xz

sudo ldconfig
go get github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go
```

But the test failed with the `go test github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go`, there is the error message.

```
2017-11-18 06:25:59.874418: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
2017-11-18 06:25:59.877032: F tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.cc:822] Unexpected type: 23
SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x7f6c4afd70bb m=7 sigcode=18446744073709551610
signal arrived during cgo execution

goroutine 24 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.cgocall(0x656610, 0xc4200439c8, 0xc4200439f0)
    /home/qcg/share/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:132 +0xe4 fp=0xc420043998 sp=0xc420043958 pc=0x405434
github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go._Cfunc_TF_SetAttrTensor(0x7f6c24003c10, 0x7f6c2400e060, 0x7f6c2400e250, 0x7f6c2400e1f0)
    github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/_test/_obj_test/_cgo_gotypes.go:890 +0x45 fp=0xc4200439c8 sp=0xc420043998 pc=0x52cb25
github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go.setAttr.func18(0x7f6c24003c10, 0x7f6c2400e060, 0x7f6c2400e250, 0x7f6c2400e1f0)
    /home/qcg/share/g/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/graph.go:273 +0xec fp=0xc420043a00 sp=0xc4200439c8 pc=0x538d0c
github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go.setAttr(0x7f6c24003c10, 0xc42000e0c0, 0x6ef103, 0x5, 0x6b60c0, 0xc4200e2440, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/qcg/share/g/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/graph.go:273 +0x11b9 fp=0xc420043c00 sp=0xc420043a00 pc=0x52f759
github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go.(*Graph).AddOperation(0xc42000e080, 0x6eef64, 0x5, 0xc42001a8d0, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc42007af00, 0x4b36cb, ...)
    /home/qcg/share/g/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/graph.go:176 +0x4a0 fp=0xc420043d60 sp=0xc420043c00 pc=0x52e3a0
github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go.Const(0xc42000e080, 0xc42001a8d0, 0x6, 0x6827a0, 0xc4200e22c0, 0xc42001a8d0, 0x6, 0x4d463d, 0x7aaad0)
    /home/qcg/share/g/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/util_test.go:38 +0x221 fp=0xc420043e38 sp=0xc420043d60 pc=0x529d41
github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go.TestOutputDataTypeAndShape.func1(0xc4200fa780)
    /home/qcg/share/g/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/operation_test.go:137 +0x11e fp=0xc420043fa8 sp=0xc420043e38 pc=0x53619e
testing.tRunner(0xc4200fa780, 0xc4200e2400)
    /home/qcg/share/go/src/testing/testing.go:746 +0xd0 fp=0xc420043fd0 sp=0xc420043fa8 pc=0x4d46e0
runtime.goexit()
    /home/qcg/share/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2337 +0x1 fp=0xc420043fd8 sp=0xc420043fd0 pc=0x45f831
created by testing.(*T).Run
    /home/qcg/share/go/src/testing/testing.go:789 +0x2de

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
testing.(*T).Run(0xc4200fa000, 0x6f51c9, 0x1a, 0x702600, 0x47b201)
    /home/qcg/share/go/src/testing/testing.go:790 +0x2fc
testing.runTests.func1(0xc4200fa000)
    /home/qcg/share/go/src/testing/testing.go:1004 +0x64
testing.tRunner(0xc4200fa000, 0xc420053de0)
    /home/qcg/share/go/src/testing/testing.go:746 +0xd0
testing.runTests(0xc4200e2220, 0xa413c0, 0x11, 0x11, 0xc420053e78)
    /home/qcg/share/go/src/testing/testing.go:1002 +0x2d8
testing.(*M).Run(0xc420053f18, 0xc420053f70)
    /home/qcg/share/go/src/testing/testing.go:921 +0x111
main.main()
    github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/_test/_testmain.go:82 +0xdb

goroutine 20 [chan receive]:
testing.(*T).Run(0xc4200fa3c0, 0xc420014860, 0x13, 0xc4200e2400, 0x2)
    /home/qcg/share/go/src/testing/testing.go:790 +0x2fc
github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go.TestOutputDataTypeAndShape(0xc4200fa3c0)
    /home/qcg/share/g/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/operation_test.go:136 +0x56e
testing.tRunner(0xc4200fa3c0, 0x702600)
    /home/qcg/share/go/src/testing/testing.go:746 +0xd0
created by testing.(*T).Run
    /home/qcg/share/go/src/testing/testing.go:789 +0x2de

rax    0x0
rbx    0x7f6c37ffeaa0
rcx    0x7f6c4afd70bb
rdx    0x0
rdi    0x2
rsi    0x7f6c37ffe840
rbp    0x7f6c37ffea90
rsp    0x7f6c37ffe840
r8     0x0
r9     0x7f6c37ffe840
r10    0x8
r11    0x246
r12    0x7f6c37ffecc0
r13    0x17
r14    0x5
r15    0x7f6c37ffecc0
rip    0x7f6c4afd70bb
rflags 0x246
cs     0x33
fs     0x0
gs     0x0
FAIL    github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go  0.052s
```

Any ideas? Thanks. Any more details needed?  Any more details needed?  Any more details needed?  Any more details needed?  Any more details needed?

Environment:

```
OS: Ubuntu 17.10 64bit
go version go1.9 linux/amd64
gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3)
```

Comment: I updated my answer with the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already opened an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14546).

For your interest: the tensorflow package works fine (as you can read from the conversation in the issue). You can just comment out the lines that make that test fail, or just skip the `go test` command and use it (maybe use it with [tfgo](https://github.com/galeone/tfgo), that will make your life easier).

Update:

to fix the issue we just have to checkout the go package to the release 1.4:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go
git checkout r1.4
go test
```